# How to notify the backend if the user clicks on the refresh button in a list view in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

react-admin provides an ootb refresh button in a list view by default.
When the user clicks on it, the data is requested from the backend in the same way as when the user opens the list view page for the first time.

My backend fetches data from a third system and caches it. In the backend I need to distinguish between two situations:

1. the user opens the list view -> deliver cached data
2. the User clicks refresh -> refresh the cache (fetch data from 3rd system) and deliver data

My idea now is to add another parameter to the GET request only if the user clicks on refresh, so that the backend can react to it and refresh its cache.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add another query parameter to API calls if they are tiggered by the refresh button on react-admin. That's because the Refresh button only forces a rerender of the entire page, which re-runs the exact same fetching code as for the original render.

Your best bet, in your case, is to replace the default RefreshButton by a version of your won, that does two things in a row:

1. call the special route in your API asking to refresh the cache
2. dispatch the refresh action (as in the original RefreshButton), which will trigger the rerenred and the refetch of all dataProvider calls.

Something like:

```
const RefreshButton = ({
    label = 'ra.action.refresh',
    icon = defaultIcon,
    onClick,
    ...rest
}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const handleClick = useCallback(
        event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            fetch('/my/api/refresh').then(() => {
                dispatch(refreshView());            
            })
            
            if (typeof onClick === 'function') {
                onClick(event);
            }
        },
        [dispatch, onClick]
    );

    return (
        <Button label={label} onClick={handleClick} {...rest}>
            {icon}
        </Button>
    );
};
```

Comment: How do I actually replace the default refresh button in the top blue bar?

Comment: You must write a custom toolbar, see https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#replacing-the-appbar